# Network Link Conditioner crashes on Mountain Lion

Tags: xcode, macos

When I try to start the Apple network link conditioner on Mountain Lion (10.8.5) I get the error:

Preferences Error
Could not load Network Link Conditioner preference pane.

Console says:
05.11.13 10:06:16,845 System Preferences[705]: com.apple.Network-Link-Conditioner failed to load.
-[SFAuthorizationView setAsyncOperation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff3f31e40d0

I'm using the latest Xcode 5.0.1 and the latest hardware io tools (october 2013).

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Update: The version "late July 2012" (Nov 26 2012) seems to work. But:what's the difference?

Comment: Any purticular reason for staying in mountain lion when maveriks is free?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I'm using a program which doesn't perform well on Mavericks.

Answer (score 1):

On my computer, the NLC PreferencePane also crashed when I tried to click the switch to turn it on.

I found out that it works when I logged in as Admin and not as a Standard user.

Comment: this is still the case for macOS Siera 10.12